# merge result of multiple select using linq and entityframework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, parent-child

how can merge result of this 3 line

```
var newscatid=Dbcontext.tbl_NewsPosition.where(x => x.Fk_NewsID==4 and     IsMainPosition=true).select(x => x.Fk_NewsCatId);

from p in Dbcontext.tbl_cat.where(x => x.Id== newscatid) select new {    parentCat = b.CatName};
from ch in Dbcontext.tbl_cat.where(x => x.Fk_ParentId== newscatid) select new { childCat = ch.CatName};
```

This is what I’m trying to obtain:

```
+-----------+----------+
| parentCat | childCat |
+-----------+----------+
| Sport     | Footbal  |
|           |          |
+-----------+----------+
```

and these are my tables:

[image]

[image: tbl_NewsPosition]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var result = from p in Dbcontext.tbl_cat
    join ch  in Dbcontext.tbl_cat on p.Id equals ch.Fk_ParentId
    join np in Dbcontext.tbl_NewsPosition on p.Id equals np.Fk_NewsCatId
    where np.Fk_NewsID==4 && np.IsMainPosition
    select new { parentCat  = p.CatName, childCat = ch.CatName };
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below code:

```
   var newscatid=Dbcontext.tbl_NewsPosition.where(x => x.Fk_NewsID==4 and     
   IsMainPosition=true).select(x => x.Fk_NewsCatId);'

    var data = 
    from p in Dbcontext.tbl_cat
    join ch in Dbcontext.tbl_cat on p.Id equals ch.Fk_ParentId
    where p.Id==newscatid
    select new 
    { 
      parentCat  = p.CatName , 
      childCat  = ch.CatName
    };
```